# VBA GoalSeek Loop Issue

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am a novice regarding VBA and in my first code I try to make a loop through 2 columns (P and J) for a GoalSeek function.

The set cells are P2 then P3 then P4 etc.
While the change cells are J2 then J3 etc.

I want to iterate from row 2 till row N (the number N is stored in the cell D1)

Here's what I wrote:

```
N = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reverse DCF").Range("D1").Value

Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To N
     Range(Cells((i), "P")).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range(Cells((i), "J"))
Next i
```

I get an error message:

```
 "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed.
```

I am sorry but I don't see the problem with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *Cells* without *Range*. Here is an working example. Make sure cell `N`contains an integer and P*i* to P*N* contains formulas.

```
Sub GoalSeekTest()

Dim N As Integer
Dim i As Integer

N = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reverse DCF").Range("D1").Value

    For i = 2 To N
        If Cells(i, "P").HasFormula Then
            'Messagebox for clarification
            MsgBox ("Formula cell: " & Cells(i, "P") _
                .Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False))

            Cells((i), "P").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Cells((i), "J")
        Else
            MsgBox "Cell " & Cells(i, 1) _
                .Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False) _
                & " has no formula - skipping this cell!", _
                vbCritical, "Formula required!"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your reply,

Basically this line is the function Goal Seek:

Range(Cells((i), "P")).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range(Cells((i), "J"))

For a simple cell it is like this:
Range("P2").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("J2")
And for a simple cell the code works.

I don't want to set the value to 1. I want to use the Goal Seek function that changes a cell (variable) until the target cell (a function) reach a certain value (here 0) by iterations.